# read tcp via event

Tags: c#, events, tcp, modbus

I'm kinda new to C# and I'm trying to create a Modbus-TCP slave.

All i want to do is to call an event handler when i recieve data from the TCP Master.

```
namespace Mark_II.Device
{
    class Slave_TCP : mSlave
    {
        short trans_ID;
        byte[] Respond;       
        byte[] MasterMessage;
        TcpClient Client;
        NetworkStream stream;


        public Slave_TCP(String IP, int Port)
        {
            Client = new TcpClient(IP, Port);

            stream = Client.GetStream();
            // insert "call event handler" here<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        }


        private void client_OnReceiveData(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {  
            byte[] message = new byte[Client.ReceiveBufferSize];                       
            stream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);

        }
    }
}
```

I have been looking around but i couldn't find anything... please help me.

tl;dr: I'm looking for a way to raise an event, when my Client receives data from a master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, events in C# works like this:

```
public delegate void MessageHandler(string message);

public class Client
{
   public event MessageHandler MessageArrived;

   public void CheckForMessage() //logic to check if message is received
   {
     //other code to check for message
      if(MessageArrived != null)
         MessageArrived("message received");
   }
}

public class DisplayMessage
{
  public void DisplayMessage(string message)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", message);
  }
}
```

Code to hook up an event:

```
 public class ProcessMessage
 {
    Client client = new Client();
    DisplayMessage msg = new DisplayMessage();
    client.MessageArrived += new MessageHandler(msg.DisplayMessage);
    client.CheckForMessage();
 }
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much for answering
I'll check if i can put it in my "new" code somehow, but how can i Connect this "CLient" with the C# Class "TCPClient" ? isn't it an object in an object?

Comment: It is hard to tell without looking at your code. But if you want `TcpClient` to generate `event` then use `client` class code in the `TcpClient`. Please mark it as answer if it works for you.